# How to get OpenGL ES2 to compile with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Qt program to compile and link against OpenGL ES2 functions.

I've created a simple program that uses a QGLWidget to draw some simple triangles in my Qt application using the old OpenGL 1.0 pipeline.  I'd like to use advanced 2.0 features like VBOs and shaders, so I started simply enough by trying to allocate some buffers for a VBO:

```
int ids[2];
glGenBuffers(2, ids);
```

Unfortunately, my project cannot find glGenBuffers() and I get the error message

```
GlWidget.cpp:103: error: 'glGenBuffers' was not declared in this scope
```

The start of qgl.h had the line "#elif defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2)", so I tried setting that for the preprocessor, but it still couldn't find glGenBuffers().

I'm not sure what to try next.  Please let me know how I can get my Qt program to use OpenGL ES2.

Here's the output I get when I compile:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=/C/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/dev/kitfox.com/biz/monsterRacing/proj/CharacterEditor'
/C/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/qt-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/CharacterEditor.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/dev/kitfox.com/biz/monsterRacing/proj/CharacterEditor'
g++.exe -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtCore' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtGui' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtOpenGL' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/ActiveQt' -I'.' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/mkspecs/default' -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
g++.exe -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtCore' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtGui' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtOpenGL' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/ActiveQt' -I'.' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/mkspecs/default' -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/MainForm.o MainForm.cpp
MainForm.cpp: In member function 'void MainForm::openFile()':
MainForm.cpp:78: warning: unused variable 'surfSet'
g++.exe -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtCore' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtGui' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/QtOpenGL' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/include/ActiveQt' -I'.' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/mkspecs/default' -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GlWidget.o GlWidget.cpp
GlWidget.cpp: In member function 'void GlWidget::buildMesh()':
GlWidget.cpp:103: error: 'glGenBuffers' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/dev/kitfox.com/biz/monsterRacing/proj/CharacterEditor'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/GlWidget.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/dev/kitfox.com/biz/monsterRacing/proj/CharacterEditor'
```

Comment: Which OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation are you using?

Comment: What is your platform? OpenGL ES is for Embedded Systems.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Whatever came with Qt when I installed it.  I'm using Qt 4.6.2 with MinGW.  Pretty much, I followed the instructions on this page: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/qt-applications.html

Comment: Okay, I'm not really using OpenGL ES2 because I'm developing for desktop and not an embedded device.  It's actually regular OpenGL 2.  However, I do try to restrict myself to the ES2 subset of OpenGL.

Comment: My platform is Windows 7 with an NVidia Quadro graphics card.  I've done OpenGL 2 development before in other languages, but am new to Qt.

Comment: can you please link the includes of your project. Sounds like you are missing GLU.h or GLEW support (though I think it is most probably the first).

Answer (score 0):

You Might Need GLEW. Here are some links to look at.

[GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net)

[Initializing GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)

[Here's where I got those links](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/594823-glgenbuffers-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/)

Sorry if it's not what you're looking for.